# Unable to call two consecutive api methods, one for create a user and one for delete the created user

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a problem while developing my api, i have some calls, like CreateUser, DeleteUser, GetAllUser etc. and no matter what, i cannot make consecutives create and delete user calls.
When i call the create user method, returning the user id, i cannot delete the newly created user, it will return a 404 not found status code.

I've tried with postman, using the runner collection, and it gives no errors, it works fine, so i think it's a problem with my api calls, and not with my controller method.
I've also tried to create a little console app for test (attached), following the example on the microsoft documentation, with no luck, 
At this point i'm not sure what may be the problem, i tought about an sql problem, maybe it doesn't have time to create the row, before i delete it, but in postman works fine, so... , or maybe a problem with async calls, but i always wait for result, so i think it's fine.

```
    static string _basicAuthenticationUser = "UserTest";
    static string _basicAuthenticationPassword = "Password";

    static string _email = "user@gmail.com";
    static string _password = "test";

    static UtentiApiModel userToCreate =
    new UtentiApiModel
    {
        Nome = "Alex",
        Cognome = "Hello",
        Email = "user@gmail.com",
        Password = "test",

    };

    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var authValue = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{_basicAuthenticationUser}:{_basicAuthenticationPassword}")));

        client = new HttpClient()
        {
            DefaultRequestHeaders = { Authorization = authValue }
        };

        RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();    
    }

    private static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1045/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var id = await CreateUserAsync(userToCreate);

        var statusCode = await DeleteUserAsync(id);

        Console.WriteLine(statusCode.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task<long> CreateUserAsync(UtentiApiModel utente)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(utente);

        var content = new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
            "test/", content);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var reslt = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UtentiApiModel>(reslt).Id;
    }

    static async Task<HttpStatusCode> DeleteUserAsync(long id)
    {

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.DeleteAsync(
            "/test/"+id+");

        return response.StatusCode;
    }
```

[image: Sql calls order]

Comment: Have you verified that Id is actually coming back fine and is deserialized and passed on to DeleteUserAsync properly?

Comment: Yes, the id is fine, actually if i put a debug break point after the unsuccessful delete call, wait a bit, and run the delete call again, it will work fine, the problem is when i run them one right after the other.

Comment: It indeed looks like a concurrency problem then. What would happen if you try to use a different `HttpClient` instance for the Delete call?

Comment: I've tried that, i put every call in a using new httpclient, but no luck...

Comment: I did some other tests, actually i don't think it's a concurrency problem, i've tried putting one debug break point on the create method that execute the sql quey, and another one on the delete method.
The sequence is correct, but at that point the stored procedure will not find the user.
Maybe it's an sql problem, but if it's that, i don't understand why postman works.

Comment: Maybe a deadlock?? If you're not using a different thread try ConfigureAwait(false): HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("test/", content).ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: I'v also tried ConfigureAwait(false) but nothing changed, as i said, i don't know if it's a concurrency problem, debugging the controller i see that the calls are called in the right sequence, and the row is actually created before the delete, so i can't understand what's the problem.

Comment: Is it running against SQL Server?  If so, can you try and use the profiler to see in what order your statements are being executed at the database level?

Comment: I've attached the sql server profler result to the post, as you can see the calls are in the right order (Create First, and getById after that, there is a getbyid and not a delete, because i check the existence of the user before remove it), and even if is the order is right and the id is right, the row is not found.